# Remove Patched Product on Wix Bundle Uninstall

Tags: wix, bundle, patch, uninstallation

I have a bundle which installs two products: the application and a much larger resources installation.

For upgrades the application msi will apply a standard upgrade, but the resources installation gets patched instead.  (Unfortunately this process started a while ago, so the patch chain is still built using Wix 3.0).

On uninstall of the bundle the application is fully and correctly uninstalled, but the patch only is removed, leaving the full install of whatever previous version of the resources existed (downgrade from 1.5.0.0 to 1.4.0.0).

Is there a method to force a full uninstall of the full product, rather than just the .msp patch, through the bundle?

Edit:  Just to add, exposing the resources installation in Programs and Features and running an uninstall there will remove the entire product correctly as expected.

Comment: Are you using an upgrade version of the installer to go from version X to Y that only includes the msp for the resources installation? It sounds like your upgrade bundles don't know about the previous patches/original msi and are actually working as expected and *just* uninstalling the msp.

Comment: @BrianSutherland Yes, you are correct, this is the expected behavior.  I was just hoping there might be a way to let the bundle force a full product uninstall rather than just the patch, even though it ships with only the patch.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a possible solution for you.

I just tested myself a very simple bundle with one MSI in it. What I did was have the main bootstrapper installer have the msi embedded in it an install it. The second bundle had a higher version and the exact same msi reference but I set compressed="no" in the <MsiPackage> tag. When I uninstalled the upgraded bundle it also removed the original MSI.

So I think you can get your bundle to properly remove the original "Resources" installation after you've upgraded and added a small msp. You just need to add back the <MsiPackage> to the bundle chain before the msp and set compressed="no"

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.ResourcesInstaller.TargetPath)" Compressed="no"/>
```

The only caveat here is that the SourceFile should be the exact same msi that was included in your first install. When you install the upgrade, the burn engine should detect this msi as already installed so nothing would be needed to be done. When uninstalling, it will detect the msi as installed and *should* uninstall it.

I'm not completely sure this will work but it is something to try. Another nice thing about this is it will have virtually no impact on the size of your upgrade installers.